# Program that should work, but it isn't

Tags: java, string, variables, if-statement, joptionpane

```
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String name;

        name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "ENTER TEST BELOW:"," ",3 );

        if (name == "TEST") {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome " + name + ", It works "," ",  1, new ImageIcon("Pictures/Example.jpg"));

        }

        else {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Welcome " + name + ", It doesn't work."," ",  1, new ImageIcon("Pictures/Example.jpg"));

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: so what is the error?

Comment: Don't compare `String` values with `==`; use `String`'s `equals` method instead.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of comparing the strings with this:

```
name == "TEST"
```

you should use this:

```
name.equals("TEST")
```

A [famous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) explains the reason why you need to do this. Essentially, `==` compares whether `name` and `"TEST"` are the same object. They are not the same object, but they have the same contents, and `equals` tests for the same contents.